# check if my two columns contain at least one seminar value in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe with multiple columns, i want to know if there is a function that will allow me to check if i have at least one identical values in two columns.
here is a small example of my data and the desired result.
thank you for your help.

**input file :**

```
column1    column2 
France     Canada |Sweden | France | Italy
Spain      Switzerland | Canada |Sweden
```

**output file :**

```
column1       column2                               column3
France        Canada |Sweden | France | Italy      Ok
Spain         Switzerland | Canada |Sweden         NOK
```

Comment: The values of `column2` are lists or strings? Also, in input file you're missing Canada and Sweden in second row.

Comment: object both of columns

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I just asked if there is a function that will make it easier for me to solve this problem, I didn't ask you to write the code for me. I'm sorry but you're saying whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for a list comprehension:

```
df["column3"] = ["ok"
                 if pd.notna(col1) and pd.notna(col2) and (col1 in col2)
                 else "nok"
                 for col1, col2 in zip(df.column1, df.column2)]
```

which iterates over two columns together and checks if first one is in the other one (and also if neither is `NaN`); comprehension does this for all rows,

to get

```
>>> df

  column1                          column2 column3
0  France  Canada |Sweden | France | Italy      ok
1   Spain     Switzerland | Canada |Sweden     nok
```

Comment: thank you very much mustafa, i think i have a data typing problem. I will see that.

Comment: @SamiaAabad I see; if any error shows up, you can share along with the traceback.

Comment: I can't, unfortunately, because some people say that I'm just waiting for the result when I'm just sharing my problem and trying to solve it. 
anyway, let's drop it. thank you again and have a good evening.

Comment: @SamiaAabad That's interesting but I suppose they meant nothing personal, Stackoverflow is in general like that sometimes... But still, if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) the answer to signal others that the issue is somewhat resolved. If not, that's fine of course.

Comment: Aydin  It is a pity. Yes, of course I can accept that it can help other people